# Converting a Date Number String to Word in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, yii1.x

I have a PHP script outputting dates like this:

```
03/01/2023
```

Now I wish to make them output the above value as

```
Zero Three/Zero One/Two Zero Two Three
```

I have tried to create functions that return string data of that date number but did not get the exact result.

Comment: why do you want `Zero Three/Zero One/Two Zero Two Three`? that's not a meaningful representation of dates? Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can pass your single digit date value to the function and in return it will give you the word.

You will need to modify this to some bit according to your need.

```
<?php
echo $key = getWord(0);
function getWord($a){
$array = array(
'0'=>'Zero', 
'1' => 'One',
'2' => 'Two',
'3' => 'Three',
'4' => 'Four',
'5' => 'Five',
'6' => 'Six',
'7' => 'Seven',
'8' => 'Eight',
'9' => 'Nine',
);

return $array[$a];

}
?>
```